# strange print in terminal with malloc, C

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to use `malloc` to first allocate some space for an array, and then `realloc` to extend the array. The program compiles but I get some strange memory-print in the terminal when I run the program. The terminal says someting like: `======== Memory map =========` and then a bunch of numbers and stuff.

In my program, I use malloc as this:

```
struct station *addStation(struct station *graph, struct station newStation){
    graph = realloc(graph, sizeof(graph)+sizeof(struct station));
// Count the rows of graph[] here and add newStation to the end.
}

int main(){
    struct station *graph;
    graph = malloc(145*sizeof(struct station));
    graph = loadStations();
    newStation = graph[27];

    graph = addStation(graph, newStation);
}
```

Am I using it wrong?

Comment: You're leaking memory almost immediately in `main()`. Without knowing what `loadStations()` does I can't say what the behavior could be.

Comment: `"a bunch of numbers and stuff"`? That's not very specific. You should paste the exact output here.

Comment: You need to pass `graph` by address.

Comment: C is still a pass-by-value language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting the pointer where your memory is:

```
graph = malloc(145*sizeof(struct station));
graph = loadStations(); // malloc'd memory is lost here
```

If you wish to add some data to the memory, you need to pass it as a pointer instead:

```
loadStations(graph);
```

Also, your `sizeof(graph)+sizeof(struct station)` only reserves data to 1 pointer and 1 station, which is not what you want. You need to pass the existing size information:

```
struct station * addStation(struct station * graph, size_t * count, struct station newStation){
    size_t newCount = *count + 1;
    graph = realloc(graph, newCount * sizeof(struct station));
    if(!graph)
        return 0;
    *count = newCount;
    // Copy new station here
    return graph;
}
```

and call in the main:

```
    temp = addStation(graph, &graphCount, newStation);
    if(temp)
        graph = temp;
```

Comment: what does the size_t do?

Comment: @theva `size_t` is unsigned integer type which is guaranteed to be able to  hold any possible array index. It's found in `stddef.h`.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(graph)` returns the size of the graph pointer which is, for example, 4 bytes. It does not return the previously allocated size.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You don't mean `sizeof(graph)` in your `addStation()` function - that will be the size of `graph`, which is a `struct station *`, a regular pointer (and most likely 4 or 8 bytes).

You'll need a separate variable to keep count of the number of stations in your graph and then `realloc()` to the appropriate size every time.

Comment: +1 he could also use a struct with a counter and flexible array member. Either way, he needs to keep it *somewhere*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix a few things.

- Check if `malloc` was successful.

  ```
  graph = malloc(145*sizeof(struct station));
  if(graph == NULL) {
      // your failure code here
  }
  ```
- Do **NOT** overwrite the pointer to your allocated memory.

  ```
  graph = loadStations();   // Strict NO, this will cause a leak.
  ```

  instead pass the pointer in case you want to modify the data.

  ```
  loadStations(graph);
  ```
- Its easier to keep the `count` of your `stations` and pass is to `addStation`

  ```
  struct station *addStation(struct station *graph, struct station newStation, size_t *count) {
      graph = realloc(graph, (*count + 1) * sizeof(struct station));
      if(graph == NULL) {
          // your failure code here
      }

      ++(*count);

      // your code here
  ```

  }
- Free the allocated memory after use.

  ```
  free(graph);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong you initialize graph with malloc then you erase it with function return.

```
graph = malloc(145*sizeof(struct station));
graph = loadStations();
```

This is bad too because it will returt sizeof(pointer)+sizeof(structure) so 4+struct size

```
sizeof(graph)+sizeof(struct station)
```

You can't retrieve the size allocated by previous malloc using sizeof. you need to store it someplace or to store number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my comments, this looks erroneous.

You have a pointer to graph by doing a  malloc.
Now you have overwritten this pointer value by the following line.

```
graph = loadStations();
```

/** Please see my comments inline **/

```
struct station *addStation(struct station *graph, struct station newStation){
    graph = realloc(graph, sizeof(graph)+sizeof(struct station));
// Count the rows of graph[] here and add newStation to the end.
}

int main(){
    struct station *graph;
    graph = malloc(145*sizeof(struct station));

    /** graph is a pointer, why are u manipulating the graph pointer to some other value **/
    /** The following line is bad **/
    graph = loadStations();



    newStation = graph[27];

    /** This is right **/
    graph = addStation(graph, newStation);
}
```

Comment: Please [don't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).